# How to disable ping thread on jenkins agent

Tags: jenkins

One of the jenkins slave is going down very often. Found RCA for this issue. 
It's because of the Ping thread

In the logs I fetch from agent, I have:

```
Terminating the channel channel.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started at 1576130988405 hasn't completed by 1576131228405
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:134)
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:90)
```

I wanted to disable the ping thread on the agent. In the documentation it's mentioned as `-Dhudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec=-1`

But I do not understand how to execute this on remote machine.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789808/disable-pinging-slaves-in-jenkins?answertab=active#tab-top). but that solution is for JNPL. I am launching the agent on the node via ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web UI, from the home page, navigate to Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Configure.  This page has all of the health checks that Jenkins performs to determine if an executor is up.  The check you are concerned about is called "Response Time".  You can disable the "Response Time" health check on this page.

From the help text on the same page:

> This monitors the round trip network response time from the master to the agent, and if it goes above a threshold repeatedly, it marks the agent offline.
>
> This is useful for detecting unresponsive agents, or other network problems that clog the communication channel. More specifically, the master sends a no-op command to the agent, and checks the time it takes to get back the result of this no-op command.

Answer (score -1):

The executor thread is waiting on the channel to give it more data.

You got a little confused due to the fact that the ping thread has the name of the channel Object in its threads name (which is the same Object that the executor is wating for).